# Preset column value using a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can I preset the value of a column using a trigger?  I am using MySQL 5.5.54.

EDIT.  If I remove the NOT NULL constraint on c2, it seems to work.

```
mysql> USE mydb;
Database changed
mysql> INSERT INTO t(c1) VALUES(123);
ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'c2' doesn't have a default value
mysql>
```

schema:

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 02/21/17 08:26:27
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`t`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`t` (
  `c1` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c2` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`c1`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
USE `mydb`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `mydb`$$
CREATE TRIGGER `t_BINS` BEFORE INSERT ON `t` FOR EACH ROW
begin
SET NEW.c2=321;
end$$


DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could assign a default value when creating the table, so the `INSERT` will not fail, and then create the `TRIGGER` for `AFTER INSERT ON` to modify the `c2` value? Just an idea.

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera  I expect that would work, but it is effectively the same thing as removing the `NOT NULL` constraint. Thanks

Comment: I also think is that bug you posted as reply, as I tried to reproduce the problem on my box and I couldn't. Could you please try one thing for the sake of curiosity? Can you create the table defining a default value to the column c2? For instance, `create table t(c1 int primary key auto_increment, c2 int not null default 0) engine=innodb;` Do you still have the same error when inserting new rows? If not, have the new rows the value of 0 in the column `c2`, or the one set by the trigger? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you said the bug "hasn't been resolved"... That's weird, I don't have such a problem on my box.

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera  Yes, I do not provide the error if I assign a default value.  While using a default value defaults the purpose of the `NOT NULL` constraint, I believe it better communicates the intent.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a MySQL bug that was submitted on 27 Oct 2004 23:30 and hasn't been resolved.  Reference https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=6030. I cannot find any other documentation.

Two solution are to remove the `NOT NULL` constraint, or keep the `NOT NULL` constraint and provide a default value.

> This WorkLog originated from BUG#6295 (TRIGGERS ARE NOT PROCESSED FOR
>   NOT NULL COLUMNS).
>
> The problem is that if a column is declared as NOT NULL, it is not
>   possible to do INSERT NULL (or UPDATE to NULL) even though there is
>   associated trigger, setting NOT-NULL value.
>
> For example:
>
> - Table 't1' with a NOT NULL column 'c1';
> - The table has BEFORE INSERT trigger which sets the 'c1' column
>     to not null value (SET NEW.c1 = 1);
> - INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(NULL)
>     or
>     UPDATE t1 SET c1 = NULL
>     fail with the following error:
>     ERROR 1048 (23000): Column '' cannot be null
>
> The cause for the current (wrong) behavior is that the column
>   constraints are checked before triggers are executed.
>
> This is against The Standard, which requires that column constraints 
>   are checked at the end of an SQL statement.